# Linux source, where are sys_umount and sys_mount system calls?

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, source, system-calls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding the linux kernel source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/797/understanding-the-linux-kernel-source)

I am **sure** that I must be missing something, here.  I cannot for the life of me find the source code for these system calls.  I can find their numbers, and I can find their prototypes, but I cannot seem to actually find the functions that implement them.

In case anyone's interested: the reason that I am trying to find them is so that I can debug a problem with the kernel's floppy driver and/or my floppy drive itself.  I can dd to/from it just fine.  The drive works in DOS and Windows just fine.  But when I mount a disk (any disk, doesn't matter what), the disk is mounted for approximately 1/10 of a second and then automatically unmounted.  I am trying to find out why and if there is a way that I can patch my kernel locally to work around it.

I know, I know, nobody uses floppies anymore.  But I guess I am a nobody.  :)

Comment: Yeah, the question that this is allegedly a duplicate of doesn't actually say anything about these system calls.  I did see that question.  I did read it.  But the answers were basically "uh, they're somewhere, but it's not regular". Additionally, I am looking for the switching points, not the implementations (I don't care about ext3 umount, I want VFS umount).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They <strike>are</strike> were in [`fs/super.c`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#aivgwOHmhBo/mirror/users/t/tpoole/linux-2.4.tgz|c8aorrNkcYs/linux-2.4/fs/super.c&type=cs) in Linux 2.4:

- [sys_mount](http://www.google.com/codesearch#gAPqQmMlpWI/fs/super.c&q=sys_mount&type=cs&l=843)
- [sys_umount](http://www.google.com/codesearch#aivgwOHmhBo/mirror/users/t/tpoole/linux-2.4.tgz%7Cc8aorrNkcYs/linux-2.4/fs/super.c&q=sys_umount&l=1117)

In my machine (Linux 2.6.24) they are in [`fs/namespace.c`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#gufiwQeQ0iA/trunk/kernels/linux-2.6.16-gazineu/fs/namespace.c):

- [sys_mount](http://www.google.com/codesearch#3C3saXwSWsQ/trunk/linux-2.6.24.3/fs/namespace.c&q=sys_mount&l=1550)
- [sys_umount](http://www.google.com/codesearch#3C3saXwSWsQ/trunk/linux-2.6.24.3/fs/namespace.c&q=sys_umount&l=631)

In Linux 2.6.39 (which is latest stable) I could not find `sys_mount` function but I found `compat_sys_mount` function in `/fs/compat.c`.

Thanks to [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) for pointing out obsolete information.

Comment: They *were* in `fs/super.c` in a very old version of the kernel. They're in `fs/namespace.c` now. [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/linux) is the place to search.

Comment: @Gilles You are right, but there is no version info in question. So haven't realized that my information is obsolete. Anyway, I have updated my answer with additional references.

Comment: Awesome! How did you trace them to fs/namespace.c? I guess I was grepping for the wrong thing?

Comment: @Michael Actually I used Google Code Search and then verify the existance of files and functions in my system.