# How to find system call implementations in Linux/Android 2.6.29?

Tags: linux, kernel, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding the Linux kernel source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/797/understanding-the-linux-kernel-source)

I want to modify some system calls for tracing purposes. To be specific, whenever a system call `open` is made, I want to print some messages.

I have been looking into the internet and the code and I found `open.c` in `kernel/goldfish/fs/` directory. And there are many functions  in this file. How would I know which function is being called exactly. I could have written some `printk` call in all these functions to find it but I have to do it for other system calls also.

So, I have a few questions,

1) What is the best way to find implementation details of system calls?

2) I am using Kernel 2.6.29 (goldfish-Android). Are system calls implementation different in different kernel versions?

3) `strace` tells me that `msgget` ,`msgrecv` and 'SYS_24' system calls are being made. I look into `Android/bionic/libc/SYSCALLS.txt` file and msgget is not there.

But when I look into `android/bionic/libc/kernel/arch-arm/asm/unistd.h` file, I can find `msgget` there. I can't understand what's going on and then how can I find implementation for `msgget` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question might be better suited to http://android.stackexchange.com/.